# How do I get and use stun and turn servers for my swift webrtc app?

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, stun, turn

I am a beginner to Webrtc and I am having trouble understanding how I can purchase stun and turn servers for my ios app that I want to launch.

1)I can only find free servers, but can I use them for my app when it is in production?

2)What websites can I use to get stun and turn servers?

3)Do I have to host the servers or will the server provider host it for me?

Thank you for your help in advance!